# how to enter only character in Regex - C#?

Tags: c#, regex

i have textbox and i need to check if he contain only character

how to do it with Regex in C# ?

thank's in advance

Comment: Better to be done with `mytextbox.Text.Length == 1` rather than regex - unless you're after a specific set of characters.

Comment: If this is an ASP.NET textbox, it's not safe to rely on setting the length to 1 - someone could still craft a form POST with a longer field. Have to check it at server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way to do that would be `^.$`.

This means only one character between the start and end anchors.

Feel free to change `.` to any other limitation to suit your purposes.

And keep in mind, there may be other ways to do what you want. For example, if it's a WPF `TextBox`, you can set properties on the text box itself that will [restrict lengths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength.aspx) without you having to worry about regexes.